modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'openafs': Exec format error raspberry pi
Why am I getting this Exec format error listed below while attempting to install the openafs client on a raspberry pi?
[rpi][dotfiles][100]$ sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-6.1.0-21-arm64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.1.0-21-arm64 is already the newest version (6.1.90-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up openafs-client (1.8.9-1) ...
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'openafs': Exec format error
Failed to load openafs.ko.  Does it need to be built?
dpkg: error processing package openafs-client (--configure):
 installed openafs-client package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openafs-client
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
_[rpi][dotfiles][100]$ 

dmesg says:
[491845.462900] module openafs: unsupported RELA relocation: 311    

This happened after installing some of the following packages:
apt-get install -y openafs-{modules-dkms,client,krb5} krb5-{config,user} libpam-krb5

Additional system info:
_[rpi][dotfiles][0]$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
_[rpi][dotfiles][0]$ uname -a
Linux rpi 6.1.0-21-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 6.1.90-1 (2024-05-03) aarch64 GNU/Linux
_[rpi][dotfiles][0]$ 


What does your dmesg say about the failing module? Is it a DKMS-built module or did the package have it prebuilt?

dmesg says: [491845.462900] module openafs: unsupported RELA relocation: 311.  Not sure if the module was prebuilt, but searching the package files shows no *ko file inside the package:
dpkg -L openafs-modules-dkms openafs-client | grep ko /usr/src/openafs-1.8.9/include/kopenafs.h /usr/src/openafs-1.8.9/src/afs/afs_chunkops.h 
I assume this means it is a DKMS-built-module.

I also noticed this message: Failed to load openafs.ko.  Does it need to be built? How would I know if it needs to be built?

If you don't have an openafs.ko in /lib/modules/, then it needs to be built; if you do have it (and modinfo openafs finds it), then it doesn't. But from your dmesg, I am guessing that it might need to be re-built for the current kernel, using dkms (probably as explained here -- or by removing and reinstalling the package).

find /lib/modules/ -name openafs.ko gives me /lib/modules/6.1.0-21-arm64/updates/dkms/openafs.ko. But lsmod doesn't list that package: sudo lsmod|grep -i afs. How can I remove or rebuild a module not listed by lsmod? I tried sudo dkms removeve -m openafs -k $(uname -r) but it asks for a version number. I'm not even sure how to get the version info for any other existing module, since modinfo doesn't seem to return a version:  line as suggested by this guide: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-version-of-ko-kernel-module-driver/

lsmod lists loaded modules; yours isn't loaded, so removing it is just removing the actual openafs.ko file. I don't know how to deal with dkms, though – if dkms status works it should return the version, but otherwise I'd likely try just removing/reinstalling the package. (Or using the kernel's native AFS support if all you need is mounting /afs.)

I removed the openafs.ko file and rebuilt the module with sudo dkms build -m openafs -k $(uname -r) -v 1.8.9 --force, then tried installing openafs-client, but now I get a slightly different error message: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'openafs': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg). dmesg still says: [491845.462900] module openafs: unsupported RELA relocation: 311. I do have /afs/ but it's empty, I don't seem to have access to my cell or any cells.
